# I try to take the data from the list and do simple calculation but it errors; error said "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Tags: python, list, class, arraylist, integer

```
class bus:

  def __init__(self, name):

       self.seat = []
       self.name = name
       self.color = color
       self.passenger = []
       
      
  def input(self):

            s = int(input("Enter the number of seat %s bus: "%(self.name)))
            self.seat.append(s)
            p = int(input("Enter the number of passenger in %s bus: "%(self.name)))
            self.passenger.append(p)
  def display(self):

        print (self.name, "bus color is ", self.color," and have", self.seat, "seats","and have",self.passenger,"passenger")
  def p(self, b=None):

    if b is None:
      self.seat = [int(i) for i in self.seat]
      b = str(self.seat)
      print(str(self.seat)+4)

      


name = input("Enter the name of bus driver:")

color = input("Enter the color of ther bus: ")

b1 = bus(name)

b1.input()

b1.display()

b1.p()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear. You cannot concatenate a string ant an integer.

`print(str(self.seat)+4)`
should be:

`print(str(self.seat)+str(4))`

Additionally, please format your code, it's basically unreadable

Comment: His code here should work without the str() since he is using a comma(',') and not the plus sign('+')

Comment: @MarioKhoury you're right, I grabbed the wrong line. The error is actually in p()